# Bootstrap tabs registering event via jQuery/Javascript when the tab is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, bootstrap-4

I have an HTML structure like following:

[image]

So now I'm trying to register an event when one of the tabs are pressed (t gets  added an class called "active")

I tried the following:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
       var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab
       // Target should be activated tab with its # id 
       console.log(target);
    });
```

To see if anything will show up in console... but nothing happens here... Why is the event not firing once I change tabs? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are the tabs created dynamically?

Comment: @Zim no they are there in HTML statically

Comment: @Zim any clue why it might not be firing  ? =(

Comment: No it seems to work fine: https://www.codeply.com/go/KHnsfp7uSF